# Check if objects is foreign key of queryset result

Tags: python, django

I have a set of objects stored in a variable called `subs`. The column `subscribed_to` is a foreign object.

Is there any way to do check if a related_object is in this list in a simpler way:

```
def check_subscription_status(user, related_object):
    subs = get_user_subscriptions(user) # returns filter queryset
    subscribed = False
    for s in subs:
        if s.subscribed_to == related_object: #related object is the potential match
            subscribed = True
            break
    return subscribed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
return (related_object in [s.subscribed_to for s in subs])
```

ETA: A better way:

```
return subs.filter(subscribed_to=related_object).count() > 0
```

Comment: Your idea is right but to make it compatible with the method, the return should be `return subs.filter(subscribed_to=related_object).count()`

Comment: thanks .. another quick comment is that s.subscribed_to for s in subs is throwing an invalid syntax error.